# How to check build variant inside the module's build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following modules in my project:

```
MyProject
 - app  // the usual module that contains the java codes
 - theLibraryModule  // this is the module in question
   - theLibraryDebug.aar
   - theLibraryRelease.aar
   - build.gradle
```

The `theLibraryModule`'s `build.gradle` is below:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('theLibraryDebug.aar'))
```

Is there a way to check the build variant (debug/release) I am using and load the proper AAR in my `theLibraryModule` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up. I used the good old technique by moving the AAR files to `app/libs` folder. I deleted my `theLibraryModule` module, then added the following in my app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation files('libs/theLibraryDebug.aar')
    releaseImplementation files('libs/theLibraryDebug.aar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code to check the Build variant in your Gradle.

```
    // Customize your APK name here
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def appId = variant.applicationId// com.exampleFree.app OR com.examplePaid.app
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = variant.versionCode // e.g 1.0
            def flavorName = variant.flavorName // e. g. Free
            def buildType = variant.buildType.name // e. g. debug
            def variantName = variant.name // e. g. FreeDebug

            //customize your app name by using variables
            outputFileName = "${buildType}.apk"
        }
    }
```

For  [More](https://androchef.com/customize-the-apk-file-name-for-android-product-flavors/)

Comment: And how do I access the build variant from another module's build.gradle file?